# Install R packages from the command line

Tags: r

I need to build a reproducible R installation from the command line.  Seems easy enough, so I created a file with my package names of interest, for example

packages.txt:

```
ggvis
glmnet
caret
```

The an R script called installPkgs.R:

```
f = read.csv('packages.txt', header=FALSE)
z = install.packages(f[,1], repos='https://cran.rstudio.com')
```

And then I should be able to run this from the command line:

```
Rscript installPkgs.R
```

When I do, the packages are downloaded but not installed.  What am I missing?

Comment: What output are you getting? You’re probably overlooking a specific error message which aborts installation. Did you install all the external requirements of the package (these are not installed automatically)?

Comment: The output shows the packages being downloaded, and then a line stating "The downloaded binary packages are in /var/folders/blahblahblah . At that point it just stops with no other output.

Comment: I also added 'dependencies = TRUE' to the install.packages() call - same result.

Comment: You're sure the packages aren't installed? That's the normal message you get when a binary package is installed successfully. Since it's a binary, there's no need for compilation or fancy installation.

Comment: Yep.  I specifically looked for packages that were not yet installed on my system.  I also added a library(blah) line after the install and indeed it gives an error.  If I run install.packages('blah') from R or from within RStudio, it works fine.  It just seems to not work when I run it from an Rscript call.  Based on the responses, I assume this "should" work - is that a correct assumption?

Comment: I think it is a dependency problem.  I tried to install a couple of packages that have no dependencies outside of what is already installed, and they seemed fine.  But when a package has other dependencies that are not installed, it appears to fail.  Also, I tried install.packages('blah') from within an R session and it seemed find for the same package that fails when attempted using RScript.  This was the case even when I set dependencies = TRUE in the install.packages() call.

Comment: Urgh.  I found the problem.  In my code, the list of packages is being interpreted as a factor rather than character strings.  So, I need to set the parameter in read.csv() or the global parameter stringsAsFactors = FALSE.  Urgh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question so that the answer is obvious and not buried into the coimments.

In my code, the list of packages is being interpreted as a factor rather than character strings. So, I need to set the parameter in read.csv() or the global parameter stringsAsFactors = FALSE.

Urgh.

Comment: Another reason to use readr `read_csv`. Although I think R in recent versions changed stringsAsFactors to default to false.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that not even requires a script file - good choice for Dockerfile etc.:

```
Rscript -e "install.packages(c('ggvis', 'glmnet', 'caret'), repos='https://cran.rstudio.com')"
```

Answer (score 1):

With a small change the above code can accept package names from the command line:

```
install.packages(commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE), repos='https://cran.rstudio.com')
```

So running:

`Rscript installPkgs.R "ggvis" "glmnet" "caret"`

should achieve the same result as the above without needing the text file.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Generally, answers try to take into account the operating context (if plausible/possible). You solution does work, dispenses with the text file (the operating context, perhaps simplifying the OP's life), but wouldn't directly point to overlooking stringsAsFactors as the error in this instance. Anyway, I like your approach as well.