# How do I install packages using the command line?

Tags: r, macos, terminal, tidyverse

I've been trying to run an R script which uses tidyverse and readr. The script itself calls the library(foo) commands to load packages and runs perfectly well in Rstudio, but does not run when invoked via "Rscript foo.R."

When I open an R terminal and call install.packages("tidyverse") I get the following confirmation:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.3/tidyverse_2.0.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 428470 bytes (418 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 418 KB
```

The downloaded binary packages are in

```
/var/folders/xg/c2dzw1391xn2zgf2mrv0b4zc0000gn/T//RtmpFAN5MN/downloaded_packages
```

I'm insure how to proceed. I've uninstalled and wiped my entire R environment, reinstalling fresh from CRAN. I've also confirmed this new install properly creates the desired output. However, I only get the following error when I run "Rscript foo.R":

> $ Rscript foo.R
> Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
> Execution halted

I see a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405551/install-r-packages-from-the-command-line) stating to try running the following:

> Rscript -e "install.packages(c('ggvis', 'glmnet', 'caret'), repos='https://cran.rstudio.com')"

This returns another error:

```
string_bidi.cpp:11:10: fatal error: 'fribidi.h' file not found
#include <fribidi.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [string_bidi.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘textshaping’
removing ‘/opt/homebrew/lib/R/4.3/site-library/textshaping’
```

I then run `pkg-config harfbuzz fribidi --cflags` and `pkg-config harfbuzz fribidi --libs`. This yields:

> Package fribidi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
> Perhaps you should add the directory containing `fribidi.pc'
> to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
> No package 'fribidi' found

and

> Package fribidi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
> Perhaps you should add the directory containing `fribidi.pc'
> to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
> No package 'fribidi' found

Comment: The [`textshaping`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textshaping/index.html) package requires a few additional OS libraries (not R) installed as well, namely "freetype2, harfbuzz, fribidi", have you installed them (and likely whatever dev versions may accompany them)?

Comment: This seems to have solved it. It looks like the fribidi dependency was missing. Thanks!